# how do i extract specific string from cell in excel?

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have lots of data which contains numbers (from 2 to 3 digits) that I wish to extract from cells with pretty inconsistent format, here is the example:

```
SRK XXXX SCNO-200 3X2X
SRK XXXX SCNO 200 20X20X
SRK XXXX SCNO-25 20X2X
KOS YYYY SCNO 25 20X2X
```

So I only need `-200`, `200`, `-25`, `25` etc. and I have to place them into a separate column.

If someone knows how to help.

I tested following string and thought it might be used for regex macro.

```
\s|\-|\d{1,3}\s
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you may use [`-?\d{2,3}(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/eRLynR/2) regex. Or even `-?\b\d{2,3}\b(?!\S)`

Comment: Split(Trim(Split("SRK XXXX SCNO 200 3X2X", "SCNO")(1)), " ")(0)

Comment: formula: `=--(MID(A1,FIND("SCNO",A1)+4,FIND(" ",A1,FIND("SCNO",A1)+5)-FIND("SCNO",A1)-4))`

Comment: I am new to this, if someone can write a complete macro code it would mean a lot.

Comment: Btw thank you very much for the formula! Great

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot rely on any static elements, and `SCNO` is just arbitrary text, and all you know is that the number you need is just a standalone 2 or 3 digit sequence with an optional `-` in front, you may use the following regex:

```
-?\b\d{2,3}\b(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eRLynR/3/)

**Details**:

- `-?` - an optional `-`
- `\b` - word boundary
- `\d{2,3}` - 2 to 3 digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\S)` - a negative lookahead making sure there must be a whitespace or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

See the sample VBA demo:

```
Sub ExtractSomeMatches()
Dim rx As RegExp
Dim m As MatchCollection
Dim n As Match
Dim s As String

s = "SRK XXXX SCNO-200 3X2X " & vbCrLf & "SRK XXXX SCNO 200 20X20X" & vbCrLf & "SRK XXXX SCNO-25 20X2X" & vbCrLf & "KOS YYYY SCNO 25 20X2X"

Set rx = New RegExp
With rx
   .Global = True
   .Pattern = "-?\b\d{2,3}\b(?!\S)"
End With


Set m = rx.Execute(s)
If m.Count > 0 Then
  For Each n In m
    Debug.Print n.Value
  Next
End If

End Sub
```

[image]